# colorize characters based on some shape without clipping

Tags: pstricks

In pst-text-doc.pdf (texdoc pst-text) page 8 describes how to clip part of a textblock using huge the letters "PSTricks".

Is it possible instead of clipping just to colorize the text inside the letters PSTricks?
(the non clipped text outside the huge PSTricks letters) will still show with a different color.

Answer (score 1):

Works only with `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-text}
\usepackage{setspace,multido}

\begin{document}

\DeclareFixedFont{\RM}{T1}{ptm}{b}{n}{3cm}
\DeclareFixedFont{\Rm}{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}{2mm}
\begin{pspicture*}(\linewidth,3cm)
\rput{60}(0.5\linewidth,1.5){%
    \begin{minipage}{0.6\linewidth}
        \setstretch{0.5}%
        \multido{\i=1+1}{500}{\Rm PSTricks }
    \end{minipage}%
}%
\begin{pscharclip}[linewidth=0.1pt]{%
  \rput(0.5\linewidth,1.5){\RM PSTricks}}%
\rput{60}(0.5\linewidth,1.5){%
  \begin{minipage}{0.6\linewidth}
  \setstretch{0.5}%
  \color{red}%
  \multido{\i=1+1}{500}{\Rm PSTricks }
  \end{minipage}%
}%
\end{pscharclip}%
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, thank you. And I guess that 0pt for the linewidth at \begin{pscharclip}[linewidth=0.1pt] instead of 0.1pt will delete the boundary of the clipping characters...